# Add new column based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table in python:

| Country | Year | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | 2020 | 2020-08-10 |
| Germany | 2020 | 2020-08-10 |
| Italy | 2019 | 2020-08-11 |
| Spain | 2019 | 2020-08-20 |
| Spain | 2020 | 2020-06-10 |

I would like to add a new column that gives 1 if it's the first date of the year in a country and 0 if it's not the first date.

I've tried to write a function but I'm conscious that it doesn't really make sense `

```
def first_date(x, country, year):
    if df["date"] == df[(df["country"] == country) & (df["year"] == year)]["date"].min():
        x==1
    else: 
        x==0
```

`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Let's create a `groupby` object to get the min index of each country so we can do some assignment using `.loc`

As an aside, using `if` with pandas is usually an anti pattern - there are native functions in pandas that help you achieve the same thing whilst taking advantage of the vectorised code base under the hood.

Recommend reading: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['Country'])['Date'].idxmin(), 'x'] = 1

df['x'] = df['x'].fillna(0)

   Country  Year       Date    x
0    Spain  2020 2020-08-10  0.0
1  Germany  2020 2020-08-10  1.0
2    Italy  2019 2020-08-11  1.0
3    Spain  2019 2020-08-20  0.0
4    Spain  2020 2020-06-10  1.0
```

---

or using `np.where` with `df.index.isin`

```
import numpy as np 

df['x'] = np.where(
       df.index.isin(df.groupby(['Country'])['Date'].transform('idxmin')),1,0)
```